# Switching between 2010 and 2013 visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have this situation,I developed a series of tools in 2013 however I have now changed job and they only work in 2010, and we are not allowed to install Visual Studio 2013

Is there a way to easily convert to 2010 and back to 2013.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: VS 2010 through 2013 projects are largely inter-compatible.  Have you tried to open your projects in VS2010?  What was the result?  As long as your projects do not require features found only in VS2013 they should be compatible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433802/is-visual-studio-2013-compatible-with-2010-projects

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433166/to-open-a-visual-studio-2013-project-with-visual-studio-2010

Comment: @CodeCaster I have changed the compatability to .net 4 and now I can open in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you haven't added features that are not supported by VS 2010, you can use them in VS 2010.

You should however check this Compatibility Matrix:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh266747%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

Directly quoted from that page:

> If you use Visual Studio 2013 together with Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2010 SP1, you can create and modify projects and files in any of the three versions. You can transfer projects and files among the versions as long as you don't add features that are not supported by one of the versions.